# ESI callback does not work from a theme

Tags: caching

I use https://www.drupal.org/project/esi module.

I have declared the function:

> function _my_devel_esi_test() {   return 'ESI test is successful!';
> }

,
which has the callback

> $items['my-devel/esi_example'] = array(   'title' => '',   'page
> callback' => '_my_devel_esi_test',   'access callback' => TRUE,   );
> return $items;

I invoke this function in a theme:

> [esi:include src="http://example.com/my-devel/esi_example" /]

but it does not work.